# how to get javascript variable inside style tag

Tags: javascript, css

Here I

```js
    var prop= document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="header"]')[0].getAttribute("class");
    var class_name= "."  + prop ;
```

```css
class_name {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="_69x2sms" data-name="header">
  <div class="_18tvv4h">
    <a target="_blank" href="">
        <span>Done
            <span class="_qx8n3fw">..!</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    </div>
  <div class="_8sfqbvd">have fun</div>
</div>
```

am trying to get JavaScript variable i.e "class_name" inside style tag the code goes here and class="_69x2sms" is dynamic here

```
<div class="_69x2sms" data-name="header">
  <div class="_18tvv4h">
    <a target="_blank" href="">
        <span>Done
            <span class="_qx8n3fw">..!</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    </div>
  <div class="_8sfqbvd">have fun</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var prop= document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="header"]')[0].getAttribute("class");
    var class_name= "."  + prop ;
</script>

<style>

class_name {
    display: none;
}   
</style>
```

Comment: you should use [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
Like that: `document.querySelector('[data-name="header"]').classList`.

Comment: class="_69x2sms" is dynamic here sorry i did nt mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let class_name = document.querySelector('[data-name="header"]').getAttribute("class");  //this will get the class of attr data-name


document.querySelector('.' + class_name).style.display = 'none'; //this will set it's display to none;

//You can directly also do so ↓↓--

//document.querySelector('[data-name="header"]').style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div class="_69x2sms" data-name="header">
  <div class="_18tvv4h"><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Done<span class="_qx8n3fw">..!</span></span></a></div>
  <div class="_8sfqbvd">have fun</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can edit the contents of a `<style />` -element the same way you would any other. At least in any moderately modern browsers (>IE9, I believe).

For example:

```
// Your JS
var prop= document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="header"]')[0].getAttribute("class");
var class_name= "."  + prop ;
// New JS
var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
style.textContent += class_name + ' { display: none; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not append some thing in already built "STYLE" Tag but you can create one like this:

```
var css = class_name +'{ display: none }',
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style');
```

`head.appendChild(style);`

```
style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your solution to the problem is probably not the best way to go about it.
If you want to modify dynamic elements with css, you could create a static class for them:

```
.custom_class {
    display: none;
}
```

and then append the class to some elements with `element.classList.add("custom_class");` instead of trying to modify existing classes.